# Is there a way to extract the function used in NetEncoder[{"Function", ... }]?

Tags: neural-networks, introspection

Is there a way — programmatically and with **documented** functions — to extract the function used in a `NetEncoder[{"Function",...}]` type encoder? I want to be able to find the association used in a language model and invert it. I have already tried two  methods:

- using the *undocumented* function `` NeuralNetworks`Private`EncoderApply`getEncoderFunction[enc] `` to get a pure function, and
- using `InputForm[enc]` and copying and pasting the result from the notebook.

```
enc = NetEncoder[{"Function", 
   Function[Lookup[<|"hi" -> 1, "bye" -> 2|>, #]], {1}}];

(NeuralNetworks`Private`EncoderApply`getEncoderFunction[enc][[1, 1, 1]] 
  /. Lookup -> List)[[1, 1]]

(* returns <|"hi" -> 1, "bye" -> 2|> *)
```

Comment: I don't really understand your question. You have already presented two different working approaches to extracting the function. What is wrong with these two approaches? Do they not always work?

Comment: The only programmatic way of doing it that I could find was using an undocumented function.  My question is: "Is there some documented way of doing it?" I could not find it, but maybe I missed it.  I was expecting Information to work, but NetEncoder has no properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`NetExtract`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NetExtract.html).

```
NetExtract[enc, "Function"]
(* Lookup[Association["hi" -> 1, "bye" -> 2], #1] & *)
```

Comment: Embarrasingly simple    I had not realized that `NetExtract[..., All]` returns the full association.